# Formatting text inside a label in windows app

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

I want to add text to my label as: area(m^2) but 2 should be in power of m.

Is it possible in .NET to do this?

Comment: `myLabel.Text += "area(m^2) but 2 should be in power of m";`

Comment: you can do that in WPF as far as I know, if that is helpful tell me to bring up the WPF code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
<Label Content="2 power of 3 => 3 &#x00B2; " />
```

instead of `U+00B2` i wrote `&#x00B2;`

But if you want to write it by C# code you have to use the first format

```
label.Content = "\u00B2";
```

Comment: great, its done. can you please tell me the link for these type of formatting. so that I can do other type of formatting...

Comment: @user1584662 See this [list of Unicode subscripts and superscripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).

Answer (score 1):

Use the superscript 2 character `²` (unicode U+00B2).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make arbitrary text superscripted, you can set the [Inlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines) property of a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run Text="area (m"/>
        <Run Text="2" BaselineAlignment="Superscript"/>
        <Run Text=")"/>
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

You might also reduce the `FontSize` of the superscripted text.

If you really need the control to be a Label, you could use the above TextBlock for the Label's `Content` property:

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Inlines>
            <Run Text="area (m"/>
            <Run Text="2" BaselineAlignment="Superscript"/>
            <Run Text=")"/>
        </TextBlock.Inlines>
    </TextBlock>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the WPF solution to your problem :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <FlowDocumentReader>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Span>number</Span>
                <Span BaselineAlignment="Superscript">2</Span>
                <Span>number</Span>
                <Span BaselineAlignment="Subscript">indexed2</Span>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentReader>
</Grid>
```

which gives you the result in the picture below :

[image]

Comment: but how to add this paragraph to the label

Comment: @HBMAAM sorry i was away, if you want to do it in a label you need to use different tags, your answer will be the same thing Clemens answered. good lock

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet would be to add a second label to hold '2' and place is higher than label 1 to give it a feel like its a square.

Comment: That's not flexible or easily reusable.